# Do we have any reference of solochain using DPOS consensus?

Tags: consensus, aura, proof-of-stake

In our solochain currently our chain using POA. Now we want to update the consensus to Delegated Proof of Stake(with AURA).
Do we have any reference or suggestion for that implementation?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few chains in our ecosystem using DPoS. You can start here:

- https://medium.com/kilt-protocol/the-continuing-evolution-of-kilt-protocol-limited-delegated-proof-of-stake-640403427c48
- https://github.com/KILTprotocol/kilt-node/blob/8fe2c4de746bfee57154e0b970b39f860c75b769/runtimes/spiritnet/src/lib.rs#L909-L911
- https://github.com/KILTprotocol/kilt-node/tree/develop/pallets/parachain-staking
- https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/tree/master/pallets/parachain-staking
- https://github.com/NodleCode/chain/pull/585/files

Granted, these are not "solo" chains but may be a good start for you to explore.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out this https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/main/pallet/staking/src/lib.rs.

This is our staking pallet, which is used in a parachain but does not rely on any parachain component. It can be easily transferred to a solo chain. Additionally, I have recently extracted the inflation logic, making it much simpler for you to apply your own inflation logic. Check it out here: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/pull/1310.